# convert int to date in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have column named datenum which is int type. For ex. 20220208
Need to convert datenum column type to date with YYYY/MM/DD format.
Tried to_date("datenum", 'YYYY/MM/DD') but isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Dates in Redshift (or any SQL database) do not really have any internal format.  To convert your input text dates to bona fide Redshift dates, use `TO_DATE` with the appropriate date mask:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(datenum, 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM yourTable;
```

If you really want to *view* your input dates in some other text format, then do a full roundtrip back to string, using `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(datenum, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY/MM/DD')
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: That worked. But if I filter to get last 60 days result it still considers int rather than date.
I am trying the below in where clause: datenum > current_date - INTERVAL '60 Day'

Comment: Use: `TO_DATE(datenum, 'YYYYMMDD') > current_date - INTERVAL '60 day'`

Comment: The data gets updated everyday, and a new entry is created for every user for each day. What if I want the min datenum of a user(basically the very first time the user came into the system). Can we use min somewhere in the same query, as I want that for the users who initially came into system within those last 60 days?