# convert unix epoch to date in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm working on a project in AWS redshift and I have date column in this form `1541105830796` (unix epoch) and I need to convert it to this form 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss'. How can I do that in AWS Redshift?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert int to date in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043677/convert-int-to-date-in-redshift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's an epoch timestamp, you need to use `DATEADD()` to calculate the seconds since `1970-01-01`:

```
SELECT 
      DATEADD(s, time_column, '1970-01-01') as date_time
FROM yourtable
```